# indexes with unspecific columns

Tags: sql-server, index

I have a third party database in which a large number of the tables have a 'companyID' column, and most of the queries against those tables include `companyID = @companyID` in the where clause.

[**EDIT:** In addition to the where clause, the companyID is generally also used in the order by clause of most queries: e.g. `order by companyId, otherField1, otherField2 etc..`
]

In our organisation the companyID column is **always** populated with 1 (though there is an outside chance that may change at some point in the future).

Now I am looking at creating some indexes on these tables.  SQL Server recommends some 'missing indexes' and all the recommendations contain the companyID field as the first column in the index.

Going on the principle of specifying most selective column first I would think that I should put the companyID column last, or perhaps not even have it in the index at all.  But then I'm wondering why SQL Server's missing indexes view always suggests putting it first - surely SQL Server is intelligent enough to know that every row contains the same value for that column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQL Server knows only about the column content if you're creating a index or a statistic for this column. If the companyID is always populated with 1 you never want to create an index for it - not even as last part of a multi column index. The recommended indices are sometimes stupid and should be considered as guess.

Comment: But it's not stupid here. If the column is to be added in the index, it should go first in the situation.

Comment: I disagree. If you add a unselectiv column to an index it will bring no benefit (unless as included column). It only makes the index larger and not better.

Comment: I disagree with your disagreement. There are cases when less selective column is better at first: [Myth: Most Selective First](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/myth-directory/most-selective-first)

Comment: Does the situation change if the field is used to order the results of a query and is always the first field specified in the order by (as per my edit)?  One person who I work with has suggested that having the companyID field as the first column of the index is critical to performance for that reason.

Comment: Yes, there can be situations were an unselectiv column should be the first one in a multi column index.
Furthermore we have to think about RID lookup. If the companyid isn't in the index (included or not) we need an additional lookup. If we already do this, it might be better to not add companyid..

And we need to talk about auto statistics. Without statistics on the secondardy columns the sql server will assume a distribution for us. This could lead to a inefficient plan. Your link only speaks about the aspect one concatenated index vs. multiple indices.